# Single Dropdown with search box in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdownbox, search-box

I want to add search box to a single select drop down option.

**Code:**

```
<select id="widget_for" name="{{widget_for}}">
<option value="">select</option>

{% for key, value in dr.items %}

<input placeholder="This ">

<option value="{% firstof value.id key %}" {% if key in selected_value %}selected{% endif %}>{% firstof value.name value %}</option>


{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Adding a input tags as above does not work out.

I have tried using html5-datalist and it works.
I want some other options as html5-datalist does not support scrollable option in chrome.

Can anyone suggest any other searchbox options?
They should be compatible with django-python framework.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply use select2 plugin to implement this feature

Plugin link: [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

[image]

Comment: needs redis and jquery

Answer (score 57):

There's also a plain HTML solution You can use a [datalist element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) to display suggestions:

```html
<div>
    <datalist id="suggestions">
        <option>First option</option>
        <option>Second Option</option>
    </datalist>
    <input  autoComplete="on" list="suggestions"/> 
</div>
```

*Note:Ensure that value of list attribute in input is same as the id of datalist.*

Please be advised not all broswers have (full) support for the Datalist Element, as you can see on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist).

Answer (score 17):

If you don't like external library, you can use the HTML5 element `datalist`.

Example from [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist):

```
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

Comment: this is pretty useful comment. thanks

Comment: This is useful but i've an issue of showing catched values in dropdown. I tried to use `autocomplete="off"` even then the value that doesnt exists are showing. I fetch dropdown arrays by an api.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a custom dropdown using HTML and CSS with search tag on the top which is fixed at the top of dropdown.You can use the following HTML and CSS with bootstrap:-

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-scroll">
<button class="btn btn-default event-button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span>Search</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-list">
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='item in items | filter:eventSearch'>
            <a>{{item}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS for the above code is:-

```
.dropdown.dropdown-scroll .dropdown-list{
    max-height: 233px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.dropdown-list  li{
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
}

.dropdown-list  li > a{
    color: black;
}
.dropdown-list a:hover{
   color: black;
}

.dropdown-list li:hover{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

[Screenshot of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTcfr.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can use **semantic ui** to implement this feature

https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/new.html

Answer (score -2):

Use [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage).
For Installation Process [Click Here](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)

Comment: how is this different from previous answers suggesting the same thing?